# Sql server rename a column

Tags: sql-server, rename

How to rename a column "foo" into "bar" in a table "mytable"? I tried:

```
Alter table mytable
Alter column foo bar;
Alter table mytable  change foo bar;
Alter table mytable rename column foo to bar;
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a reminder. Renaming columns is dangerous, because it might break scripts.

```
sp_rename 'MYDB.FOO', 'BAR', 'COLUMN';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SSMS, you can just right click and press "Rename"...

[image]